# How do you find one of the coordinates on a kite

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

[Question Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRdc7.jpg)

Hi Math Community,

For part b), I tried to find the coordinates using length and gradient formula to form 2 simultaneous equation and solve for unknown x and y but still couldn't get the answer. Anyone here got any alternative methods? The answer for coordinates of )point F is (-34,-17).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By considering the areas. we can say that F is on EA produced such that FA : AE = 2 : 1. In other words, A divides FE **internally** in the ratio 2 : 1.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes. Found the answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: @TanAndrew Hope that helps. If it does, please consider accept it as an answer by ticking it (located right under the down-arrow).